# update the data dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two end points

http://localhost:3000/entry (POST)

Keys are :- fname, lname and age . We can submit a form by sending a POST request to this URL.

http://localhost:3000/entries (GET)

It will return the existing data from the database in a JSON.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b48a137c3b2a3454b853a3c",
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Jose",
        "age": "28",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b506cc7d9105012f59c87e6",
        "fname": "Alex",
        "lname": "Cruz",
        "age": "27",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I can successfully submit a form. In my HTML, I also have a table. I want to update the data in the table whenever I submit an entry without reloading the whole page.

Actually, data in this API http://localhost:3000/entries is dynamic, sometimes, I insert into database directly. So, whenever there is a change, it should reflect in the table without reloading the whole page.

I am using AngularJS 1.

index.html :-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>
          Dashboard
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <form name="saveTemplateData" action="#" ng-controller="FormCtrl"  ng-submit="submitForm()" >
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>FirstName</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" ng-model="form.fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>LastName</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" ng-model="form.lname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label>Age</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" ng-model="form.age" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ngClick="Submit">
      </div>
    </form> 


    <!-- Table Start -->

    <div class="row">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- item.fname -->
          <td>{{item.fname}}</td>
          <!-- item.lname -->
          <td>{{item.lname}}</td>
          <!-- item.age -->
          <td>{{item.age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Table END -->

  </div>
</div>
```

script.js :-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.submitForm = function()
            {
                $http({
                        url: "http://localhost:3000/entry",
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        data: $.param($scope.form)
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                    }), function (error) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                    };
            }
});
```

Comment: Use **AJAX** calls. It's for what you want i.e. to update web pages (or some of its parts) without reloading it, which is good. Please check https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp.

Comment: firstly, make sure you prevent the default behaviour of submit buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and problem(s), you'll need to do a number of things to resolve your issues.

Firstly, you'll want to make some extensions to your controller. The main one being to fetch the data from your API:

```
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

/*
Add this method to get data from server
*/
$scope.fetchData = function() {

    // It is best practice to handle error responses as well (not 
    // shown here)
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/entries').then(function(response) {

        // Set the data items in your scope. Doing this should now 
        // cause them to be listed in your view
        $scope.items = response.data;
 });

}

$scope.submitForm = function($event) {

    // Adding this prevents the browser from reloading on form submit
    $event.preventDefault()

    $http({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/entry",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: $.param($scope.form)
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.status = status;
        }), function (error) {
            $scope.status = status;
    });
}

// Fetch data once controller is set up, on a regular 2 second 
// interval
$interval(function() {
   $scope.fetchData()
}, 2000)
});
```

You'll also need to update your HTML/view:

```
<!-- Add $event as an argument to you ng-submit callback -->
ng-submit="submitForm($event)"
```

And:

```
<!-- Doing this causes the data in the items array to be iterated
     and displayed in a list-wise fashion in the table -->
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- item.fname -->
    <td>{{item.fname}}</td>
    <!-- item.lname -->
    <td>{{item.lname}}</td>
    <!-- item.age -->
    <td>{{item.age}}
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Finally, the most important thing is to wrap the table and form with your `FormCtrl` controller. You can do this by moving `ng-controller="FormCtrl"` from your `<form>` element, to your `<div class="container">` element in your view.

Comment: It is giving error :- Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined . Also data in the table is not showing

Comment: Also, I don't need to update the data via form. I will do the required update from the database itself. So, whenever there is a change in the JSON it should reflect in the table.

Comment: please see update regarding preventDefault issue. Are you saying that you want your app to periodically re-fetch the data from the server , to reflect changes in the data stored in the data base?

Comment: preventDefault error is not coming. But data is not showing in the Table.

Comment: okay, didnt catch that from your original question. see the addition of `$interval` at the top and bottom of the controller, to achieve the automatic fetching on a (2 second) interval

Comment: see the updated answer, at the very bottom - you need to make sure `<div class="container">` has `ng-controller="FormCtrl"` and not the `<form>`

Comment: I did the same, but still same issue